# filter extracted data using xpath

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath

i am using the following code as input to dom document

```
<li id="SalesRank">
<b>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</b>
#20,267 Paid in Kindle Store (
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=pd_dp_ts_kstore_1/190-9295683-0277616">See Top 100 Paid in Kindle Store</a>
) 
<ul class="zg_hrsr">
<li class="zg_hrsr_item">
<span class="zg_hrsr_rank">#15</span>
<span class="zg_hrsr_ladder">
in 
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_kstore_1_1">Kindle Store</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/154606011">Kindle eBooks</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157325011">Nonfiction</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/292975011">Lifestyle & Home</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156699011">Home & Garden</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156828011">Gardening & Horticulture</a>
 > 
<b>
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156847011">Greenhouses</a>
</b>
</span>
</li>
<li class="zg_hrsr_item">
<span class="zg_hrsr_rank">#26</span>
<span class="zg_hrsr_ladder">
in 
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_kstore_2_1">Kindle Store</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/154606011">Kindle eBooks</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157325011">Nonfiction</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/292975011">Lifestyle & Home</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156699011">Home & Garden</a>
 > 
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156828011">Gardening & Horticulture</a>
 > 
<b>
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156849011">House Plants</a>
</b>
</span>
</li>
</ul></li>
```

i am using the following xpath query to extract data with textContent..

```
$xpath_cat->query('//li[@id="SalesRank"]');
```

you can check the output, it includes the data which is including in all the `li` tags with `id=salrsrank...` while i want to get only the `#20,267 paid in kindle store..`

so the output required is

> **#20,267 Paid in Kindle Store**

how can i modify my xpath to get the required output?

**Update in code**

i tried the solution provided below and used the xpath

```
$xpath_cat->query('//li[@id="SalesRank"]/text()');
```

but now, the output is

> ( [0] => [1] => #20,267 Paid in Kindle Store ( [2] => )

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `//li[@id='SalesRank']/text()` work for you?

**Update 1**

If the text you want will always be in that location, then

```
substring-before(normalize-space(//li[@id='SalesRank']/text()[2]), ' (')
```

will return

```
#20,267 Paid in Kindle Store
```

This uses `normailize-space` to strip out extraneous whitepspace, and `substring-before` to select all text before the first occurence of " (".

This problem will be much easier if you can get the target text in its own node, like:

```
<b>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</b>
<span>#20,267 Paid in Kindle Store</span> (
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=pd_dp_ts_kstore_1/190-9295683-0277616">See Top 100 Paid in Kindle Store</a>
)
```

`<span/>` has no effect on rendering and allows you to specifically select the text you want.

If either the second solution doesn't work in all cases, and you cannot get the target text in its own now, you **will have** to rely on some post-processing in the host language (PHP I presume).

Hope this helps,

Comment: i tried this, the count of result should be 1 in number(obviously, I need only first text() ), but count of result using this code is 3 .

Comment: @NewBee I added a more specific solution, geared 100% to the format o f the input you originally posted.

Comment: should i use it in xpath query?

Comment: @NewBee Yes, that should be a valid XPath query--it works in XSL, not sure about PHP.  And again, this only works if the data format conforms to your example 100% of the time.  Please let me know what the outcome is.  If not, PHP has far greater capabilities than XSL/XPath for selecting/manipulating strings.

Comment: just like, the result of xpath is empty..although $xpath_cat->query('//li[@id="SalesRank"]/text()'); returns result..but changing to substring-before(normalize-space(//li[@id='SalesRank']/text()[2]), ' (') retuns nothing

Comment: $nodelist = $xpath_cat->query("substring-before(normalize-space(//li[@id='SalesRank']/text()[2]), ' (')"); is the xpath i am using

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that `$element` is [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) containing `<li id="SalesRank">...`

If you do something like this:

```
foreach( $element->childNodes as $node){
    echo get_class( $node) . "\n";
    // Print content too for debug:
    // echo $node->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

You should get results like:

```
DOMText // \n
DOMElement // <b>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</b>
DOMText // #20,267 Paid in Kindle Store (\n
DOMElement // <a ...
...
```

So `$element->childNodes->item( 2)->nodeValue` **should** contain your string (do your homework, check each iteration, check documentation for each element).

Than you can simply get string until first `(`:

```
$text = $element->childNodes->item( 2)->nodeValue;
$pos = strpos( $text, '(') - 2; // Add handling for no occurance
return substr( $text, 0, $pos);
```

Or you could iterate trough all child nodes and check it on the fly

```
foreach( $element->childNodes as $node){
    // Example, rather use regexp with preg_match
    if( (get_class( $node) == 'DOMText')
        && (strncmp( $node->nodeValue, "\n#", 2) == 0)){
        // Tadaaa
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you want solution that will kill few kittens:

```
preg_match( '~(#([\d,]+) ([^<>(]+))~', $element->nodeValue, $match);
```